# ¿Cómo funciona el método de este código?

Tags: java, eclipse, metodología

En un ejercicio tengo que decir que imprimiría un programa. Ya vi con eclipse que muestra esto **4 2 3 4 4 6**, pero no entiendo como funciona el código en la parte del método. El programa es este.

```
int [] c0= {1, 2, 3, 4};
int [] c1= {1, 2};
 //se usa todo el vector c0 y solo el 2 del vector c1
c1 = metodo(c0, c1[1]);
//después de que el método se haya ejecutado, se cambia 
//el primer valor de c0 (1) por el segundo valor del 
//nuevo c1 (que imagino que será 4)
c0[0] = c1[1];

for (int i = 0; i < c1.length; i++)
    System.out.print(c0[i] + " " + c1[i] + " ");
}
//el vector c2 es igual al vector c0 
//y int a=2
static int[] metodo(int[] c2, int a) {
    //en esta parte supongo que se crea el vector c4 con  
    //una longitud de 3
    int[] c4 = new int[3];
    //se le dan valores a c4
    for (int i = 0; i < c4.length; i++) {
        //se multiplica el entero a, que es 2, por el valor 
        //que corresponda de c2 
        c4[i] = a * c2[i];
        //en esta parte no entiendo que acaba siendo ese valor de 
        //c2
        c2[i] = c2[i]++ + 1;
    }
    return c4;
}
```

Comment: Que parte no entendes?

Comment: Recuerda que siempre debes mostrar un avance de lo que has hecho. En este caso podrías agregar comentarios a cada instrucción del método explicando lo que tú piensas que hace.

Comment: @gbianchi  como funciona el programa a partir de esta parte static int[] metodo(int [] c2, int a)

Comment: @Lobos ya están agregados, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> en esta parte no entiendo que acaba siendo ese valor de c2

**En resumen:** `c2[i] = c2[i]++ + 1;` solo es una forma confusa de incrementar `c2[i]` en una unidad.

---

El valor inicial del arreglo `c2` es: `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Veamos lo que pasa con la instrucción `c2[i] = c2[i]++ + 1;` en la primera iteración:

Evaluemos el lado derecho: `c2[i]++ + 1;`. La parte interesante ( confusa ) es esta `c2[i]++`, como es un operador de post incremento; la expresión, al reemplazar las variables, queda así:

`c2[i] = 1 + 1`

El operador de post incremento primero usa el valor actual de la variable y luego la incrementa, por esa razón, aunque no se ve, `c2[i]` ahora vale 2.

Pero luego de resolver: `c2[i] = 1 + 1`, el valor de `c2[i]` se sobreescribe y ahora es 2 ( 1 + 1) y el post incremento no tuvo efecto.

Entonces la instrucción `c2[i] = c2[i]++ + 1;` es equivalente a `c2[i] = c2[i] + 1;` y también a `c2[i]++;` y también a `++c2[i];`